# Selecting an item on an AppCompatActivity's ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-appcompat

I have an AppCompatActivity. In there I have a list view. I want to make it so when an item is selected something happens (another activity will fire off, but for now I just want to get into the method where I can call that intent).

Im not sure how to do this. I saw I can hae my AppCompatActivity implement AbsListView.OnItemClickListener and it gives me a method

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
```

But then when I run my code and I select an item it doesnt go into that method.
So can someone tell me how I do this?

Below is my entire code for the activity.

```
public class RouteList extends AppCompatActivity implements AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener, AbsListView.OnItemClickListener {
    ArrayList<RouteItem> itemsList;
    ArrayList<String> routeFiles;
    ArrayList<RouteItem> selected;
    RouteListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_route_list);

        itemsList = new ArrayList<RouteItem>();
        selected = new ArrayList<RouteItem>();

        adapter = new RouteListAdapter(this, R.layout.route_list_item);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.routeList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(this);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Routes");
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getRouteFiles();
        RouteLocationsTask task = new RouteLocationsTask(adapter, routeFiles, getApplicationContext());
        task.execute();
    }

    public void getRouteFiles()
    {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/LocationTracker/Routes/";

        // Read all files sorted into the values-array
        routeFiles = new ArrayList();
        File dir = new File(path);

        String[] list = dir.list();
        if (list != null) {
            for (String file : list) {
                if (!file.startsWith(".")) {
                    routeFiles.add(file);
                }
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(routeFiles);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {

        int x = adapter.getCount();
        RouteItem routeItem = adapter.getItem(position);
        if(checked)
            selected.add(adapter.getItem(position));
        else
            selected.remove(adapter.getItem(position));

        mode.setTitle(String.valueOf(selected.size()));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.listview_cab_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.delete:
                itemsList = adapter.getItemList();
                itemsList.removeAll(selected);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                deleteSelectedFiles();

                mode.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        selected.clear();
    }

    public void deleteSelectedFiles()
    {
        for(RouteItem routeItem : selected)
        {
            File file = new File(routeItem.getFileName());
            file.delete();
        }
    }

    //@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        int y = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `setOnItemClickListener` method on ListView in order to receive callback in `onItemClick`. Just put this line in your `Activity`'s `onCreate` method.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Or if you mean by "selected" a long press, then you have to long click the item you want to select (because it's complicated for the user to have click and longclicklistener)

Comment: Really shouldnt have missed that. Thanks